# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.urls'

Tags: python, django, beeware

I am working on a app using BeeWare (front-end python app framework) and Django. I'm using a cookie cutter template. My issue is with two files: `settings.py` and `urls.py` in the following repo structure.

When I run `python manage.py runserver` inside the `webapp` dir, the server runs perfectly. But when I want to run the app development in the main app directory, named `positron`, I use `briefcase dev`. With this command, I get import errors that are fixed by changing the import statements in `settings.py` and `urls.py` from `webapp.urls` to `webapp.webapp.urls` and `webapp.views` to `webapp.webapp.views` respectively.

I would like to not have to change these import statements based on whether I am developing my Django backend or my front end BeeWare code. What would standard practice be? Should I do  a `try` statement or maybe some sort of custom package install? I'm not really sure what the most robust way to do it is.

Thank you so much!

[repo structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBqpM.png)

Comment: why would you need to switch running directory

Answer (score 0):

The `src` directory in a Briefcase app is the root of the package hierarchy, so if you want your package to be called `webapp` rather than `webapp.webapp`, just get rid of the the outer `webapp` directory and move its content directly underneath `src`.